# Wordpress querystring format from ?param=value to /param/value

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I've added a querystring var to wordpress [like this](http://www.webopius.com/content/137/using-custom-url-parameters-in-wordpress) and now I need to change the notation from ? to slashes, so these

```
http://example.com/myweb/page-1/?param=value
http://example.com/myweb/page-2/?param=value
http://example.com/myweb/page-3/?param2=value
```

appear like this:

```
http://example.com/myweb/page-1/param/value
http://example.com/myweb/page-2/param/value
http://example.com/myweb/page-3/param2/value
```

I tried in .htaccess with no luck and saw [this post explaining it](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/) but I can't take it to work, I'm bad at regular expressions and this particular example is diffuclt to debug, so I'd appreciate some help.

This is my code:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules)
{
    $aNewRules = array('page-1/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=page-1&param=$matches[1]');
    //ALso tried $aNewRules = array('myweb/page-1/([^/]+)/?$' => 'myweb/index.php?pagename=page-1&param=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

// hook add_rewrite_rules function into rewrite_rules_array
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Thank you